# Making a logo clickable

Tags: hyperref, logos

I'm wondering if there is any possibility to make a clickable logo like in html 
code, it would be like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{link_adress}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo}}   
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to do something like that but which works?

Comment: Where should the link point to? A web page, or somewhere internal to the document?

Comment: @Werner yes a web page for example , if it's the logo of the university , the link will be the official site of that university